# Searching issue in the published app in Playstore

Tags: android

i have newly Published a free app in playstore " ABC Jungle ". But if a search with a ABC i am not able to find it. only in case of " ABC jungle "search keyword i am able to find the app.

Is there any way to get my app listed if users search with "ABC".

And how to get the app listed in the first page of the search result. like what are all the parameters used by google to get the app displayed in the first page?

Answer (score 0):

About to getting on first page then depends on google. But you can add keyword in your description finished and that keyword was used by google to get your application listed when the word was match to the search text

Your Description

keyword:
ABC, abc, ABC Jungle, jungle abc..., etc